# How To display Admob interstitial every time a button is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I would like to know how to display a Admob interstitial ad every time a button is pressed. I have managed to display a interstitial ad, but only on the first time the button is pressed. Here is my code:

```
package com.mycash.borgjake.mycash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import static com.mycash.borgjake.mycash.R.styleable.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;


Button btnClick;
Button btnWithdraw;

TextView txtBalance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    txtBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String countValue = txtBalance.getText().toString();
            int dblCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue);

            if(mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitial.show();
            }

            dblCountValue++;
            txtBalance.setText(String.valueOf(dblCountValue));


        }
    });

    mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("...");
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .build();
    mInterstitial.loadAd(request);

}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Withdraw.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: call  mInterstitial.loadAd(request); after user close the Interstitial add.

Comment: how would i go about doing that?

Comment: mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            
             @Override
             public void onAdClosed() {
                 // Proceed to the code.
               
             }
         });

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line in buttons onClick() method above all,

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();
mInterstitial.loadAd(request);
```

Answer (score 1):

load your ads whenever user clicks on button, so you need to write your code inside `btnClick.setOnClickListener`

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();
        mInterstitial.loadAd(request);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am a beginner to android development. I am sorry, but I am not understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

First you need to declaire your InterstitialAd and AdRequest variables as globally something like..

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
private AdRequest adRequest;
```

Then add this code in your activity oncreate method..

```
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("PUT YOUR DEVICE TEST ID HERE").build();
```

Then write this code in button click..

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
                mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ADD YOUR ADUNITID HERE");
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    public void onAdLoaded() {
                        showInterstitial();
                    }
                });
```

And finally add this method in your activity class and run you project..

```
private void showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
}
```

I hope this will work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
mInterstitial.loadAd(request);
```

in your button click listener after showing it.

Final code ;

```
package com.mycash.borgjake.mycash;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.view.View;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;

import static com.mycash.borgjake.mycash.R.styleable.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;


Button btnClick;
Button btnWithdraw;

TextView txtBalance;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

mInterstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);

AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

txtBalance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String countValue = txtBalance.getText().toString();
        int dblCountValue = Integer.parseInt(countValue);

        if(mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitial.show();
        }
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
          .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
          .build();
        mInterstitial.loadAd(request);

        dblCountValue++;
        txtBalance.setText(String.valueOf(dblCountValue));


    }
});

mInterstitial.setAdUnitId("...");
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();
mInterstitial.loadAd(request);

}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Withdraw.class);
    startActivity(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Just copy&paste edited code.  :)  then read the following explainations.

Comment: I get an error. On the line of code: mInterestitial.loadAd(request);

Comment: I ve fixed the code above. Try to recopy and paste it.